# mysql - how do i get a list starting with a letter and continue with next letters?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT contact_id, last_name FROM contacts
WHERE last_name like 'B%' ORDER BY last_name limit 0, 250
```

returns only the B's.

what I need is to return 250 rows starting with the first Bs. If there are fewer than 250 Bs, then I need to get the following Cs, Ds etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caveat: This comparison works on SQL Server, I'm assuming it does on MySQL as well, but can't test it.

```
SELECT contact_id, last_name 
FROM contacts
WHERE last_name > 'B' 
ORDER BY last_name 
LIMIT 0, 250
```

Will exclude records deemed alphanumerically 'less than' B.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister I'm assuming he has no records whose last name is *literally* 'B', but good observation. :)

Comment: @sdfor Glad to help. Feel free to mark it as the accepted solution, then (click the check mark beneath the vote total). :)

Comment: I did, actually have a 'b', in my test data.  Good poin t@The Scrum Meister and I marked it @djacobson. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Most DB Engines will compare text such that this will work...

```
SELECT contact_id, last_name FROM contacts
WHERE last_name > 'B' ORDER BY last_name limit 0, 250
```

Answer (score 0):

you can OR your where statements

```
SELECT contact_id, last_name FROM contacts
WHERE last_name like 'B%' or last_name like 'C%' or last_name like 'D%' ORDER BY last_name limit 0, 250
```

and so on...

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway That's putting it... diplomatically. :S

Comment: might get nasty but if you are looking at non contiguous starting alphabets the accepted solution won't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

What about not like 'A%' ? ( so you will drop As and Bs will be first ) or Regexp ?

Comment: thanks, though that would require programming for different input. 'B' is only an example. @djacobson and @John K answers work